# GitLab CI Runner with relative paths in main.tex

Tags: errors, compiling, paths, continuous-integration

I have a LaTeX document where I include another TeX file with a relative path like `\include{../Meta/commands.tex}`. If I compile it on my local machine all works fine.

Now I also want to use the CI feature of GitLab. I have my runner working in a way that following file gets compiled without an error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  Hello World!
\end{document}
```

My `.gitlab-ci.yml` files looks like this:

```
compile_pdf:
  image: aergus/latex
  script:
      - latexmk -pdf -interaction=nonstopmode ./Test/main.tex
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - main.pdf
    expire_in: 1 week
```

If now the `main.tex` file contains a relative path to `\include{../Meta/commands.tex}`, then I get the following error:

```
Latexmk: Missing input file: '../Meta/commands.tex' from line
  '! LaTeX Error: File `../Meta/commands.tex' not found.'
```

Does anybody know how to resolve this unpleasant issue? Most likely I have to resolve the relative paths but I do not know how...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: can't you do `cd Test; latexmk main.tex ` so you are running in the documents directory?

Comment: note that `\include{../Meta/commands.tex}` may fail anyway it would need to write `../Meta/commands.aux` and by default tex is prevented from writing to files not under the document directory (paths starting `../`)

Comment: I propably know my mistake... I will check it tomorrow when I am back in the bureau and keep you then posted.

Thank you anyways for your suggestions!

Comment: But the `cd Test; ...` worked! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It usually works best to run tex from the document directory, so

```
cd Test; latexmk main.tex
```

rather than

```
latexmk Test/main.tex
```

Comment: I try run pipeline like yours, but because bibliography and glossary all times appear error.
You know how to solve?

Comment: @DanielSousa if you have an error message that you don't understand, post a new question showing the error and the code that causes it.